# Can I search for posts by multiple tags?

Tags: feature-request

Questions may have multiple tags, but when searching by tags, can I search by more than one tag?

[image]

[image]

Trying to enter both (as i am interesting in these tags only when combined together) i get nothing

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[]` to delimit tags, you can use multiple tag queries with them, ie: [`[wine] [packages]`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wine+packages)

[image]